# PHP regex equivalent of nth-child

Tags: php, css, regex

I need to identify some objects in an array by their position and I'm struggling with the logic. I'm looking for the **PHP equivalent `nth-child(5n + 1)` as a condition**, resulting in objects in positions `0, 5, 10, et al.` within a loop.

Logically it's probably simplest to divide by 5 and look for a whole number, e.g. `0/5 = 0 pass`, `1/5 = .2 fail`, `5/5 = 1 pass`.

If the

```php
for ($i = 0; $i < $total; $i++) {

    // obviously this doesn't work because it's nonsense :)
    $rhythm = preg_match(/^(\d+){N % 5 == 0}/, $i)

    if ($rhythm) {

        // is 0, 5, 10,
        // etc
    } else {

        // 1, 2, 3, 4,
        // 6, 7, 8, 9,
        // etc
}
```

Comment: why regex? if `$i` is a number, can't you just say `if($i % 5 === 0)`?

Comment: Of course it’s nonsense to try and use regular expressions for a mathematical operation.

Comment: Have you considered `for ($i = 0; $i < $total; $i += 5)`?

Comment: @Jorg throw that in an answer so I can accept it. Can't believe I didn't think of that. Amazing.

Comment: @TomasoAlbinoni yeah, considered it but I need to manipulate all of the objects whether or not they match. Best to separate within the loop itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regex is absolutely the wrong tool for the job. Although if you really wanted, `/[05]$/` would do it.

Try `$rhythm = $i % 5 == 0;` instead. You can change the `0` to another number (`1-4`) to do the `+1` part of the condition.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could do it like this as well.

```
for ($i = 0; $i < $total; $i+=5) {
{
   // is 0, 5, 10,
   // etc
   array[ $i ] = "whatever05";

   for ($j = 1; $j < 5; $j++ )
   {
        // 1, 2, 3, 4,
        // 6, 7, 8, 9,
        // etc

        if ( ($i + $j) >= $total )
            break;
        array[ $i + $j ] = "whatever12346789";
   }
}
```